# Saving a DataFrame as a HIVE table using spark fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big dataframe and trying to save it as a HIVE table using the following command.

```
df.write.options(Map("path" -> "/workspace/ny/df")).saveAsTable("db_name.table_name")
```

I'm allocating resources statically, but `saveAsTable` fails because of out of memory issue. I read in one of the answers to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664008/how-to-save-dataframe-directly-to-hive) that `saveAsTable` is like persist into memory. Is that correct? How can I create external tables then?

My other question is, even even my table is not big, saveAsTable takes long and I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869728/spark-data-frame-write-to-parquet-table-slow-at-updating-partition-stats) that it's because of updating some stats. Is that also correct? What sorts of stats are being calculated and how can I turn them off?

p.s. my tables are in Parquet.

Comment: what is your spark version ?

Comment: it's 1.6.0.....